# Setting default account for opening a google drive file

Tags: android, android-intent, google-drive-api

I am developing an Android app that integrates with the user's google drive account.

In my app users can send each-other files from their own drive account and open them.

When a user clicks a file I want to let the os handle the opening of the file according to the user's preference 
I do so in the code below

```
ctx.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(shareUrl)));
```

My question is, can I specify the default account to open such files?
For users with multiple google accounts on their phone, each time they click a file, they have to choose the account they want to use. 
Is there a way to add to the intent the default account to use?

Comment: Have you checked 'AccountPicker - newChooseAccountIntent'? it returns an intent to an activity that prompts the user to choose from a list of accounts. The caller will then typically start the acctivity by calling startActivityForResult. Here's a sample app: https://gist.github.com/zimdo/4018924

Comment: This is not what I want. I get this behavior from the default google drive app. I need the opposite, meaning, a way to specify the account in advance, and feed the result to the default "account picker"